# Needs space in the element name in xml formation

Tags: c#, xml, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

I've set of data in the database and needs to convert to the xml format, but the problem is one of the element name has the space between the element name but I want to use this name in the xml

```
<Data>
<Out put xml>
<ROW>
</ROW>
</Out put xml>
<Data>
```

I aware about that couldn't possible to use space in the element name. Please suggest me any other alternative to achieve this.

Comment: just remove the whitespace from the name string before using it as an element name won't fix the problem?

Comment: I agree with you it will fix the problem. but later on i want to convert back to original data. That time it wouldn't be possible right?

Comment: yes this is true, its better then to use an other delimiter like _ which you can easily replace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to encode the name while converting to xml

```
  XmlConvert.EncodeName(Name);
```

Then to convert back just decode it

```
  XmlConvert.DecodeName(Name);
```